# Chrome/Safari solution for transition delay in combination with animation

Tags: html, css

I've just tried to let an image rotate on hover and freeze it for 3 seconds when the pointer leaves. while the below works in firefox it does not in safari nor chrome. My question: Is there any solution for chrome/safari and ie to achieve this?

html

```
<div id="cat-container">
        <a href="/"><img class="cat" src="http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/75864-Space-Cat.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

css

```
#cat-container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 2em;
}

.cat:hover {
  -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-transition: 0s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0s ease-in-out;
}

.cat {
    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
   -moz-transition: .75s ease-in-out 3s;
   -ms-transition: .75s ease-in-out 3s;
   -o-transition: .75s ease-in-out 3s;
    transition: .75s ease-in-out 3s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jajxb6cg/

Comment: I think you are trying to mix a transition and an animation and that's not possible. This feels like it will be solved by Javascript.

Comment: okay, I was hoping for a pure css solution here, because it was working in ff but I guess I will go with some javascrpt then. thanks for the reply.